# A form appears for a short time and then disappears as though it had been filled in

Tags: php, forms, stripe-payments

I have a problem with a form seemingly submitting itself and I do not know enough to know where to look to find out why.

The matter is part of a Stripe Application and the code is taken more or less intact from their (php) documentation. I added some javascript
to deal with errors; I copied the javascript from Larry Ullman's article http://www.larryullman.com/2012/11/28/creating_a_form...

Firstly in index.php some data is taken from the customer, then the form action takes place in handle_form.php where data is stored
temporarily, then to page02.php where some data id downloaded for the back office and finally onto purchase.php where
the credit card details are sent to Stripe to get a token. All this worked OK. No problem at all.

However, I realised that the back office did not have the id of the quantity $charge. I needed this so as to be able to check the 
Stripe dashboard against my back office. So I altered the order of the scripts. index > handle_form > purchase (making a 
small addition to capture the $charge id) > page02.

The code seems pretty well unchanged to me. I only changed the bit of javascript which routed the control; but I must have made 
some deadly error because the form that takes the credit card details
appears for about ten seconds and then vanishes. The rest of the code is still executing because after a short while it gets to the end and states 
that the payment has been successful.

Comment: Can you post code into the question rather than linking to an external website which is an error 404 link

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not clearly explain a concise code issue and the outlay of this question is that the Asker has simply not read or utalised the extensive documentation supplied by the service provider (Stripe) *before* asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Which Stripe documentation did you use? Show us your code. Show us what Larry Ullman changed. What are your error logs? What does your browser console say?